# How to correctly handle a .Net windows service which changes frequently

Tags: .net, windows-services

I've got a windows service which is going to be be updated ~ fortnightly

I've already got all the useful code in a DLL, the service is just a couple of simple `Start` and `Stop` methods which map to identical methods in the DLL.

I use a console app to develop/debug the DLL so I was wondering; Instead of the service referencing the DLL directly and requiring an uninstall/reinstall every time I do an update, is there any downside to using the service to wrap the console application?

Which is to say, instead of...

```
Private MyService as IMyService
Sub Start()
    MyService = New MyService()
    MyService.StartAsync()
End Start
```

Doing something like...

```
Const ServiceExecutablePath As String = "C:\Blah\MyService.exe"
Private MyService as Process
Sub Start()
    MyService = Process.Start(ServiceExecutablePath)
End Start
```

That way, if I want to publish, All I need to do is stop the service, replace the executable (and relevant DLLs) and then start it again.

I haven't quite worked out how to do a graceful shutdown yet. The console app listens for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> interrupt and calls `MyService.Shutdown(Graceful:=True)` (A blocking call). Should I try to emulate the same from within the service or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an executable for this. You can dynamically load a DLL when you bring your service up.Either do it manually (see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx)), or use something like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) to load it for you.

Another easy approach is to use [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to host your service. With TopShelf, you develop and run your service as a console application. When you pass the argument install to the console app, it will be installed as a service. It makes easy to replace as you don't need installers.

Comment: We already use Unity for DI throughout. I'm aware of MEF but haven't used it. I want to keep code in the service to an absolute minimum to reduce the risk of hard to debug issues. Am I going to need much?

Comment: MEF is easy to setup (it is part of the .net framework now) and can be used side by side with your DI container, as DI is not it's primary objective, but a side effect. Take a look at the examples.

Comment: @Basic, please take a look at this TopShelf example too: http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/shelving/.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wrapping the console app I would spin up a new AppDomain in the Service, and load the dll (plug-in style) into the new AppDomain and call your methods there.  That way on stop you can tear down the AppDomain, which releases the dll for your replacement enjoyment.

Loading the dll plug-in style keeps you from having to hold an assembly reference.  And the extra AppDomain lets you unload the dll assembly without tearing down the service AppDomain (generally an unpleasant experience to work with).

I would avoid wrapping the console app because services don't generally play well with UI apps.  Your console window will still generate a UI (the console window).

Comment: That's a nice suggestion, thanks - With the added benefit I wouldn't have to translate `Stop`/`Start` into console-ese. I could also handle exceptions more easily.